# Spark Session Problem: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to start a session in Spark. I have downloaded Java Version as below:

```
java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have also installed Pyspark.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

But when I try to start a session, I got Exception Error. Code:

```
#Creating a spark connection
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(master = "local")
```

Error:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Can you help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java version (17) is too high for spark.
From Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)

```
Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, Python 3.6+ and R 3.5+
```

So you need to decrease your Java to 11 or 8.

Comment: Thank, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded Java version 11 and know it's working.

To see how to uninstall existing Java version: https://explainjava.com/uninstall-java-macos/

To download Java 11: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html